# CSS - Responsive triangle divider

Tags: html, css, divider

I am trying to create a triangle css divider. I was able to create the divider using

```
border-width: 4vw 75vw 0 23vw.
```

however, this way feels a bit sketchy. `border-with` you can't pass percentages, is this solution valid?

This is my css class:

```
.triangle {  
width: 100%;   
box-sizing: border-box;   
height: 0;   
border-style: solid;   
border-width: 4vw 75vw 0 23vw; }
```

It seems to me that 75vw is not a correct solution.

This is the divider:
[image: css divider]

Comment: what is it to look like on different viewport dimensions (tall and thin for example)? e.g. how is the angle and/or height of the sides decided in relation to width?

Comment: could you do it with clip mask, it's percentage, check here https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: check this: https://css-generators.com/section-divider/

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking if the CSS is valid syntax, the answer according to [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) is **yes**.
Your CSS only produces 1 warning about *"The box-sizing property isn't supported in **IE6** and **IE7**."*